# How can I resolve 401 unauthorised error for a put call

Tags: .net, vb.net, api, httpwebrequest, put

I am trying to update a value through httpwebrequest put call but I am getting a 401 unauthorised error. If I test in postman or swagger it works fine and the update is successful. Below is my code:

```
Dim client As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(apiUrl), HttpWebRequest)
client.Method = "PUT"
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer ")
client.ContentType = "application/json"
client.ContentLength = byteData.Length

Dim postreqstream As Stream = client.GetRequestStream()
postreqstream.Write(byteData,0, byteData.Length)

Dim postresponse As HttWebResponse
postresponse = DirectCast(client.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)

Dim postreader as New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())

Dim thePage As String = postreader.ReadToEnd
```

Comment: In this line you missed the token body ```client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer ")```
should be ```client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)```

Comment: I have added that in the code. the problem line is postresponse = DirectCast(client.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)

Comment: Please, share the error

Comment: maybe you should write ```client.GetResponse()``` instead of ```client.GetResponse``` too.

Comment: Error - The remote server returned an error. (401) unauthorized

Comment: I added client.GetResponse() but i am getting the same error

Comment: Maybe your token is expired? Test it through Postman or some tools like that and just copy and paste the Bearer token.

Comment: did that and it works fine in postman and swagger page both.

Comment: It means that you have a gap in your code, I think you missed some parameters, recheck the url, token, http method and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Just update the line

```
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer ")
```

to

```
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
```

instead of `token` you should add your Bearer token without "Bearer " word.

- Useful tool for learn about JWT - [here](https://jwt.io/)
- More about HTP 401 - [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401)